# Performance issue with sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlite

I am using sqlite as database in my application. I am getting json response and I parsed it, created modal out of it and saved in the DB.

Now the problem is : I am getting records in billions. Its slowing down the performance because it consumes one for loop in assigning json data in the modal and another to save in the DB.

I want to reduce the performance issue and want to add values (with respect to keys) directly into DB. Will anyone guide regarding the better way ?

Comment: Billions? Wow well I guess you can't really increase performance that much. But using a transaction to insert the row will speed things up. But still billions of records is going to take some time. Can you provide an simple example of the record you are inserting?

Comment: I really doubt there could really be billions of records. If each record takes 100 bytes, it would be 100GB already and that's too large to fit in any existing iOS devices. Not to mention that all data arrive as JSON response from the server...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Threads & Operation queue to increase performance of the application. Following are some links in which the URL Connection is kept inside the operation queue. You may put your JSON Parsing & loading method in Operation queue. Hope this helps to increase the performance.

[Link 1](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/)
[Link 2](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)

Let me know if it works.